# visual studio 17.1 Delay Notification when copy and paste and scroll

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I have a problem with visual studio 2022 v17.1.
when i copy and paste and scroll in the same time i get the following message
[image]

does anybody else have this issue?

Comment: How are you copying, pasting and scrolling all at the same time?